# How to control the Visibility of a textbox with radio button "IsChecked" property?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

How to control the Visibility of a textbox with radio button "IsChecked" property?

I have a Two textbox's let say txtbox1 and txtbox2 and I want to bind the visibily of both these textboxes based on the radio button IsChecked property. Below is the XAML code I am trying with:

```
<RadioButton
                x:Name="radioBtn"
                IsChecked="True"
                Margin="5"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Grid.Column="0">Enter Constant Values</RadioButton>

<TextBox Visibility="{Binding Path = IsChecked, ElementName = radioBtn}" />
```

Should I use Convertor ? Please help!!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Yes, you can use the built-in [BooleanToVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx).

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<TextBox Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=radioBtn,Converter={StaticResource b2v}}" />
```

Comment: +1, this is quite a common issue and I hope this answer becomes a Google favourite :)

Comment: For those noob to this, you'll need a <RadioButton Name="radioBtn" GroupName="group1">Basic Encryption</RadioButton> series of buttons. Just bind the ElementName to each RadioButton.Name and voila you have sections disappearing and appearing based on your selected radio button.

Comment: This was perfect for what I needed to control visibility on a text box and its associated label.