# RadioButton - hide lbl and txt box based on selection

Tags: c#

```
if(rbn1.Checked == true)
{
    lblR.Enabled = false;
    txtR.Enabled = false;
    Re = (input * 2 + inputW * 2);
    lblRe.Text = Math.Round(Re, 2).ToString();
}
```

This is the current code I have, but when I run the program and select the rbn1, it does not seem to hide the lblR and txtR.  All help is appretiated, thanks!

Comment: Put your code under the `CheckedChanged` event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control the Visibility of a textbox with radio button "IsChecked" property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361085/how-to-control-the-visibility-of-a-textbox-with-radio-button-ischecked-propert)

Comment: Thanks for the replys but .CheckedChanged didn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: I've solved the problem, thank you so much for all your help you guys! <3

Answer (score 1):

You're using .Enabled property instead of .Visible property.

```
if(rbn1.Checked == true)
{
    lblR.Visible = false;
    txtR.Visible = false;
    Re = (input * 2 + inputW * 2);
    lblRe.Text = Math.Round(Re, 2).ToString();
}
```